# How to write a custom decoder for [Option[Option[A]] in Circe?

Tags: scala, circe

I had written a `Reads` converter in play-json for `Option[Option[A]]` that had the following behavior:

```
//given this case class
case class MyModel(field: Option[Option[String]])

//this JSON -- maps to --> this MyModel:
//"{ \"field\": \"value\" }"  -->  MyModel(field = Some(Some("value")))
//"{ \"field\": null, ...  }"   -->  MyModel(field = Some(None))
//"{ }"  -->  MyModel(field = None)
```

So, providing the value mapped to `Some[Some[A]]`, providing `null` mapped to `Some[None]` (i.e. `Some[Option.empty[A]]`), and not providing the value mapped to just `None` (i.e. `Option.empty[Option[A]]`). Here's the play-json converter:

```
def readOptOpt[A](implicit r: Reads[A]): Reads[Option[Option[A]]] = {
  Reads[Option[Option[A]]] { json =>
    path.applyTillLast(json).fold(
      identity,
      _.fold(_ => JsSuccess(None), {
        case JsNull => JsSuccess(Some(None))
        case js => r.reads(js).repath(path).map(a => Some(Some(a)))
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Now I am converting my play-json code to Circe, but I can't figure out how to write a `Decoder[Option[Option[A]]` that has the same behavior. That is, I need

```
def optOptDecoder[A](implicit d: Decoder[A]): Decoder[Option[Option[A]] = ??? //help!
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work? Thanks

**I figured this out:**

There were two problems:

1) How to deal with the case where the field was completely missing from the JSON. Turns out you have to use `Decoder.reattempt` in your custom decoder, following Circe's `decodeOption` code, which works.

2) How to have the compiler recognize cases of `Option[Option[A]]` when your decoder code is sitting in a helper object (or wherever). Turns out if you're using semi-auto derivation, you can create an implicit in the companion object and that will override the defaults:

```
//companion object
object MyModel {
  implicit def myModelOptOptDecoder[A](implicit d: Decoder[A]): Decoder[Option[Option[A]]] = 
    MyHelperObject.optOptDecoder
  implicit val myModelDecoder: Decoder[MyModel] = deriveDecoder
}
```

Anyway, I don't think this will be much help to anybody in the future, so unless I get any upvotes in the next few hours I think I'll just delete this.

**Edit2:** Okay it was answered so I won't delete it. Stay strong, esoteric circe question, stay strong...

Comment: I suppose the next question would be how to get the Circe case class decoders to even look for an implicit `Decoder[Option[Option[A]]` when faced with an `[Option[Option[A]]`, since Circe seems to just happily just use its default `Option` decoder in this instance as well. Ugh.

Comment: How `Option[Option[T]]` is meaningful?

Comment: @cchantep Let's say you want to update a model in a REST API. You PATCH the JSON model to the API. Missing fields are ignored and not touched (represented by `None`). Null field values are deleted from the model (represented by `Some[None]`... that is take *some* action, and that action is overwriting with `None`). Other field values are updated (`Some[Some[A]]`). Anyway, I'm getting close to figuring this out (I think) so I'll either delete the q or answer it myself so it can rest uselessly for all eternity.

Comment: Such stacking seems weird to me

Comment: Why won't `Option[A]` decoder work for `Option[Option[A]]` ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh See my comment above? Not sure what else I can provide you.

Comment: @cchantep interesting

Comment: Maybe a custom type with 3 case would be more understandable than `Option[Option[A]]` in you case

Answer (score 2):

An `Option[Option[A]]` is a bit odd. I understand and mostly agree with the reasoning, but I think it's weird enough that it may warrant just replacing it with your own class (and writing a decoder for that). Something like:

```
sealed trait OptionalNull[+A] {
  def toOption: Option[Option[A]]
}
object NotPresent extends OptionalNull[Nothing] {
  override def toOption = None
}
object PresentButNull extends OptionalNull[Nothing] {
  override def toOption = Some(None)
}
case class PresentNotNull[A](value: A) extends OptionalNull[A] {
  override def toOption = Some(Some(value))
}
```

This has the additional benefit of not having to worry about implicit precedence and stuff like that. Might simplify your decoder.

Comment: Yeah that was actually my first approach... I was using `type MaybeOption[A] = Either[Unit, Option[A]]` as a template. BUT... this is voluminous legacy code that I'm converting from play-json to circe and I work for a startup (need I say more?) and I'd rather keep it as our weird nested option. Anyway, cheers I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/9bd7dde98957a32eb0ead604410001a1) is another solution I found (This is not my gist):

```
sealed trait UpdateOrDelete[+A]

case object Delete                                    extends UpdateOrDelete[Nothing]
final case class UpdateOptionalFieldWith[A](value: A) extends UpdateOrDelete[A]

object UpdateOrDelete {
  implicit def optionalDecoder[A](implicit decodeA: Decoder[A]): Decoder[UpdateOptionalField[A]] =
    Decoder.withReattempt {
      // We're trying to decode a field but it's missing.
      case c: FailedCursor if !c.incorrectFocus => Right(None)
      case c =>
        Decoder.decodeOption[A].tryDecode(c).map {
          case Some(a) => Some(UpdateOptionalFieldWith(a))
          case None    => Some(Delete)
        }
    }

  // Random UUID to _definitely_ avoid collisions
  private[this] val marker: String   = s"$$marker-${UUID.randomUUID()}-marker$$"
  private[this] val markerJson: Json = Json.fromString(marker)

  implicit def optionalEncoder[A](implicit encodeA: Encoder[A]): Encoder[UpdateOptionalField[A]] =
    Encoder.instance {
      case Some(Delete)                     => Json.Null
      case Some(UpdateOptionalFieldWith(a)) => encodeA(a)
      case None                             => markerJson
    }

  def filterMarkers[A](encoder: Encoder.AsObject[A]): Encoder.AsObject[A] =
    encoder.mapJsonObject { obj =>
      obj.filter {
        case (_, value) => value =!= markerJson
      }
    }
}
```